# scrollTo (jQuery) won't work in firefox

Tags: jquery, scrollto

For some reason, firefox seems to ignore my scrollTo function even though it works in chrome and safari.

Here's an example link: http://blog.rainbird.me/post/2358248459/blowholes-are-awesome

Chrome and Safari will automatically scroll to the top of the image (with an offset of 20 pixels)

It doesn't work in firefox. I'm baffled!

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".photoShell img").lazyload({
placeholder: "http://william.rainbird.me/boston-polaroid/white.gif",
threshold: 200
});


window.viewport =
{
height: function() {
return $(window).height();
},

width: function() {
return $(window).width();
},

scrollTop: function() {
return $(window).scrollTop();
},

scrollLeft: function() {
return $(window).scrollLeft();
}

};

$(".photoShell img").hide();
$(".photoShell .caption").hide();

$(".photoShell img").load(function() {

var maxWidth = viewport.width() - 40; // Max width for the image
if(maxWidth > 960){
    maxWidth = 960;
}
var maxHeight = viewport.height() - 50;    // Max height for the image
var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

        // Check if the current width is larger than the max
        if(width > maxWidth){
            ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
            $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
            height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image

        }

        // Check if current height is larger than max
        if(height > maxHeight){
            ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
            $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
            $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
            width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        }


        $(this).parents('div.photoShell').css("width", $(this).width() + 22);
        $(this).parents('div.photoShell').addClass('loaded');
        $(this).next(".caption").show();

        var scrollNum =  $(this).parents('div.photoShell').offset().top;
        $.scrollTo(scrollNum - 20, {duration: 700, axis:"y"});


            $(this).fadeIn("slow");


}).each(function() {
    // trigger the load event in case the image has been cached by the browser
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
});
```

Comment: it is working on FF, clear the cache of your browser and try again.

Comment: That's weird. I cleared my cache and it still doesn't work - I'm on firefox 3.6.13. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I am not sure

```
scrollTop: function() {
    return $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
```

with regards

Wasim

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
scrollTop: function() {
    return $(window).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
```

with regards

Wasim